# How to suppress auto statement flushing in MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis

### Background

I want to implement the following procedure with Spring and MyBatis:

1. Read a line from a CSV file
2. Query a table (table `ACCOUNT`) with values read from the CSV file.
3. Merge the values from the CSV file and table `ACCOUNT` into a record
4. Insert the merged record into another table (`REGISTRATION`)

I want to use the batch executor (`<setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="BATCH"/>`) because this procedure inserts large number of records.

### Problem

I have implemented the procedure like this:

```java
AccountDao accountDao = applicationContext.getBean("accountDao", AccountDao.class);
RegistrationDao registrationDao = applicationContext.getBean("registrationDao", RegistrationDao.class);

List<Registration> list = null;
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8"))) {

    CsvToBeanBuilder<Registration> builder = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Registration>(reader);
    builder.withType(Registration.class);

    list = builder.build().parse();
    for (Registration reg : list) {
        Account account = accountDao.findAccount(reg.getAccountId());
        reg.setName(account.getName());
            ...
        registrationDao.insertRegistration(reg);
    }
}
```

I have expected the `INSERT` SQL to be queued with JDBC `Statement#addBatch()`, and executed in a batch at the end of the transaction.

But in actually, MyBatis automatically flush every statement with `BatchExecutor#doFlushStatements()` when I query `ACCOUNT` table with `AccountDao#findAccount()`, so all `INSERT` SQL are executed separately.

In this situation, `ACCOUNT` has no relation to `REGISTRATION`, so you can safely queue the update statements and execute them in a batch.

### Question

Is there any way to suppress automated flushing of queued statements when the developer knows the queried tables have no relation to the updated tables?

Comment: I don't think there is. Using REUSE executor might help a little bit. If it has to be batch processing, you may have to use the raw JDBC API (this probably is the most efficient approach in terms of performance in your case).

Answer (score 0):

### Behaviour explanation

The batching does not work because it can be performed only when the same query consequently executed. But in your code there are two queries executed one after another: `select` and then `insert`

So each `select` breaks batching, because MyBatis has no any knowledge about what you're trying to query. The best it can do is to flush all previous inserts, so the query can be executed over actual database state

### Solution

There are only one way you can choose: select in a loop a batch of accounts and within a nested loop do an inserts

```java
AccountDao accountDao = applicationContext.getBean("accountDao", AccountDao.class);
RegistrationDao registrationDao = applicationContext.getBean("registrationDao", RegistrationDao.class);

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8"))) {

    List<Registration> registrations = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Registration>(reader)
        .withType(Registration.class)
        .build()
        .parse();
    for (List<Registration> batch : Lists.partition(registrations, 500)) {
        Map<Integer, Account> accounts = Maps.uniqueIndex(
            accountDao.getAccount(batch.stream()
                .map(Registration::getAccountId)
                .toList()),
            Account::getId
        );
        for (Registration registration : batch) {
            Account account = accounts.get(reg.getAccountId());
            reg.setName(account.getName());
                ...
            registrationDao.insertRegistration(reg);
        }
    }
}
```

### Why there is no such mechanism as in a question

IMO, it's very dangerous, because you as an original developer may definitely know, that it's safe, but another developer may not. He even may not to notice that configuration. And then add some code, that breaks your invariant. And it'll be difficult to realise where the bug is